# What does the dead tree symbolize in Blade Runner 2049?

Tags: analysis, blade-runner-2049

[image]

This tree seems to be one of the most lasting images in my brain after leaving the theater, and I have been dying to ask this question, as I am struggling to dissect its symbolic significance.

Just to sum up what importance this tree holds, firstly, this is Rachel's grave. As such, it bears the "long-buried secret that has the potential to plunge what's left of society into chaos" - the fact that Replicants can give birth. Secondly, said birth (constantly referred to as "the miracle") happened right in front of it.

There is a scene where Officer K and Mariette discuss the tree. Mariette thinks it's beautiful, while K points out it's dead. I'm trying to decipher this particular exchange, and my guess is that it shows what the tree means to each, and how differently. Mariette, a member of the Replicant Freedom Movement, clearly views it as the site of "the miracle", while K's indifference shows how he hasn't seen a miracle yet, in Sapper's haunting last words.

So that's how much I've analysed this movie, and I'm guessing there's A LOT MORE to do. **So what symbolic importance does this tree bear?**

Comment: At this point in time, it seems that this would can only generate opinion-based answers depending on one's interpretation of the film. I think at its most literal interpretation, it represents the dead mother's (Rachael) headstone.

Comment: Not if you can reason your speculation based on the actual film, which is what this site is about. At what "point in time" would this situation be any different?

Answer (score 4):

A related image to remember is that of the flower that K finds at the bottom of the tree. It is what triggers all the story since it hints him into investigating more around the dead tree. 
In a world where life is hard to find and maintain, the apparition of this flower of bright colors looks like a miracle.

The dead tree is only a part of this symbol that illustrates the miracle of life and is the message of hope that fuels the story: even after things have died, life can appear again in new things.

Answer (score 0):

The tree stands for family.
As in a family tree.

I’m not sure there are living trees in the kipple. Animals are way to expensive.
A living tree seems impossible to me, so it’s obvious to me why it’s dead.
Not sure why the wood of this tree was not robbed, maybe Sapper shot all that tried.

Anyway. 
For me the tree is there to tell me this story is about family.